# Yeshv'av-Chutzpit connection?

Tags: names, kohen-priest, tannaim

Any connection between the mishmar kehunah [Yeshv'av](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance), which was also nicknamed "Chutzpit-Shuchin" (also known as [Shuchim or Shichin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikhin), the town where they settled in) (see [here](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=47854&sid=02febaa90e4cea2be26ce6e638731f13) for example) and two of the Ten Martyrs, [Rabbi Yeshvav Hasofer](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%91%20%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah%7CTalmud%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Rabbah%2FEichah%20Rabbah%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Lekach%20Tov%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Mishlei%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Tehillim%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FOtzar%20Midrashim%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FYalkut%20Shimoni%20on%20Nach%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FYalkut%20Shimoni%20on%20Torah%7CTosefta&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance)<sup>1</sup> and [Rabbi Chutzpit Haturgeman](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%9F&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah%7CTalmud%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Rabbah%2FEichah%20Rabbah%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Lekach%20Tov%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Mishlei%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FMidrash%20Tehillim%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FOtzar%20Midrashim%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FYalkut%20Shimoni%20on%20Nach%7CMidrash%2FAggadah%2FYalkut%20Shimoni%20on%20Torah%7CTosefta&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance)?

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm aware that the mishmar was usually spelled ישבאב and Rabbi Yeshvav was spelled ישבב, but some versions mentioning the mishmar spelled it ישבב (such as [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.56b.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)) and [Melechet Shlomo on Chulin 2:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Chullin.2.4?lang=bi&p2=Melechet_Shlomo_on_Mishnah_Chullin.2.4.4&lang2=bi) wrote that the two versions are interchangeable.

Comment: Maybe they were descended from that Mishmar? No source, just a guess.

Comment: @N.T. That was my guess, but I'm wondering if there's any source. Or another explanation.